# How can i sum 2 input values using laravel-livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i want to sum 2 values.

my livewire blade codes:

```
<label>Sayı 1:</label>
<input type="text" id="a" name="a" wire:model.lazy="a">
<br>

<label>Sayı 2:</label>
<input type="text" id="b" name="b" wire:model.lazy="b">
<br>
Sonuç : {{ $result}}
```

in livewire file

```
public $result;
public $a;
public $b;

public function render()
{   
   $this->result=$this->a+$this->b;
    return view('livewire.try1');
}
```

i can not see the result on my page.

i have changed `$this->result=$this->a+$this->b;` line to `$this->result=a+b;` and it shows that `undefined variable $a`.

i have opened debugbar a and b is null.

so i could not make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, your Livewire views should always be wrapped in a single div, kind of like this,

```php
<div>
    <label>Sayı 1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="a" name="a" wire:model.lazy="a">

    <br>
    <label>Sayı 2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="b" name="b" wire:model.lazy="b">
    
    <br>
    Sonuç : {{ $result }}
</div>
```

Then I would suggest that you use a lifecycle-hook for updated to maintain the result,

```php
public $result;
public $a;
public $b;

public function updated()
{
    $this->result = ($this->a ?? 0) + ($this->b ?? 0);
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.try1');
}
```

Also, since you have the `lazy` modifier on your binding, beware that it will not update until you click away from the input, see https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#lazy-updating

Comment: sorry,but it did not work for me. i am aware of lazy modifier. and used one div block. thx for the answer.

Comment: Then you'll need to provide additional information, because the example here will work. Debugging information and the actual, full relevant code of that you are having issues with

Comment: i will try to do this with the begining. i will make new livewire.

Comment: it worked with new files. Thx.